# Can someone explain how this bitCount code works?

Tags: c, bitwise-operators, bit, bit-shift, bitcount

This is code that my TA help me get, but then I completely forgot how it worked exactly since I can't seem to get the right answer, and the interview grading is tomorrow. If anybody can  help please do. Thanks

```
* bitCount - returns count of number of 1's in word
*   Examples: bitCount(5) = 2, bitCount(7) = 3
*   Legal ops: ! ~ & ^ | + << >>
*   Max ops: 40
*   Rating: 4
*/
int bitCount(int x) {
    int m4 = 0x1 | (0x1<<8) | (0x1<<16) | (0x1<<24);
    int m1 = 0xFF; 
    int s4 = (x&m4) + ((x>>1)&m4) + ((x>>2)&m4) + ((x>>3)&m4) + ((x>>4)&m4) + ((x>>5)&m4) + ((x>>6)&m4) + ((x>>7)&m4);
    int s1 = (s4&m1) + ((s4>>8)&m1) + ((s4>>16)&m1) + ((s4>>24)&m1);
    return s1;
}
```

Comment: Execute it by hand on paper, so you can see what each expression does.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It is often easier to see what happen in the bit-related operation when you convert it to its bit representation:

Assuming the int is 32-bit, then the following are the m4 & m1 in their bit-representation:

```
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 //m4, masking across the 4 bytes
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 //m1, masking only 1 byte, the Least Significant Byte (LSB)
```

*I suppose m stands for **mask**, while 4 & 1 refer to **4** bytes and **1** byte respectively*

And then the tricky part is the s4. You might need to examine it step by step to get the idea of what it is.

Firstly, note the right-bitwise-shift and the masking with m4:

```
pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw // x
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 //m4
---------------------------------------- &
0000 000w 0000 000w 0000 000w 0000 000w //x&m4

pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw // x
---------------------------------------- >> 1
0pqr stuv wpqr stuv wpqr stuv wpqr stuv // x >> 1
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 //m4
---------------------------------------- &
0000 000v 0000 000v 0000 000v 0000 000v //(x>>1)&m4
.
.
pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw pqrs tuvw // x
---------------------------------------- >> 7
0000 000p qrst uvwp qrst uvwp qrst uvwp // x >> 7
0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 0000 0001 //m4
---------------------------------------- &
0000 000p 0000 000p 0000 000p 0000 000p //(x>>7)&m4
```

And secondly, note the addition of the 8 elements obtained from above results:

```
0000 000w 0000 000w 0000 000w 0000 000w //x&m4
0000 000v 0000 000v 0000 000v 0000 000v //(x>>1)&m4
.
.
0000 000p 0000 000p 0000 000p 0000 000p //(x>>7)&m4
---------------------------------------- +
//Resulting in s4
```

Thus, since p to w each can only be 0 or 1 and you have eight of such element, consequently, per 8-bit segment you have:

```
p+q+r+s+t+u+v+w // each element is either 0 or 1
```

From there, it can be seen clearly that the result for the addition 8 elements above would range from 0 to 8.

That is, you will get 0000 0000 (0 in decimal representation - if all is 0) to 0000 1000 (8 in decimal representation - if all is 1) per 8-bit segment.

Consequently, you will have the s4 in the following format:

```
0000 abcd 0000 efgh 0000 ijkl 0000 mnop // s4
```

Where *abcd*, *efgh*, *ijkl*, and *mnop* are the result of additions p to w per byte.

Now, notice that you get the **sum** of the number of bits in x spread across the 4 bytes.

*(**sum** I suppose this is what **s** in the variables stands for - sum)*

```
0000 abcd //byte 1, left most, MSB
0000 efgh //byte 2, second from left
0000 ijkl //byte 3, second from right
0000 mnop //byte 4, rightmost, LSB
```

Thus, you need to combine the result in those four bytes in s4 to find the **sum** in **one** byte

*(and I suppose, this is what **s1** stands for: **sum in one byte**)*

You get s1 by:

1. Shifting s4 with 0, 8, 16, 24
2. Mask each of them with 0xFF
3. And combine (add) the results.

Hence, the following operations (in the bit level) occur:

```
0000 abcd 0000 efgh 0000 ijkl 0000 mnop // s4
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 //m1 
--------------------------------------- &
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 mnop

0000 0000 0000 abcd 0000 efgh 0000 ijkl // s4 >> 8
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 //m1 
--------------------------------------- &
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ijkl

.
.

0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 abcd // s4 >> 24
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 1111 1111 //m1 
--------------------------------------- &
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 abcd
```

It can be seen that you simply have the following additions of four elements:

```
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 mnop //0 to 8
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 ijkl //0 to 8
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 efgh //0 to 8
0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 0000 abcd //0 to 8
--------------------------------------- +
//Final result, s1
```

You have simple addition of four numbers, each having value of 0 to 8. Thus, it must result in a value of 0 to 32 (0 is when all is 0, 32 is when all is 8), which is the number of bit 1 in the variable x. And thus the function is named *bitCount*.

That is how the function works.

---

Final note: knowing this, you could even change m1 with 0x0F (instead of 0xFF) and the result would still be the same.

Answer (score 0):

After this statement :

```
    int s4 = (x&m4) + ((x>>1)&m4) + ((x>>2)&m4) + ((x>>3)&m4) + ((x>>4)&m4) + ((x>>5)&m4) + ((x>>6)&m4) + ((x>>7)&m4);
```

As there are 4 bytes in S4, then 1 byte of it will have the number of 1's in corresponding byte of x
So, clearly each byte of s4 hold the number of 1's in the corresponding byte of x.

Then in statement :
 int s1 = (s4&m1) + ((s4>>8)&m1) + ((s4>>16)&m1) + ((s4>>24)&m1);

Now 1 byte of s4 will have the number of 1's in corresponding byte of x,
then right shift of s4 to 8 bits will give the number of 2's in byte 2 of x,
so on for 4 bytes.
Then adding all will give the number of 1's in x.